# View ckeditor content as html in new window

Tags: ckeditor

How to view ckeditor content as html in new modal window when a button is clicked which is placed beside the editor.
below is the html

```
 <img  src="Image/icons/preview.png" alt="Preview" id="img1" class="preview"  />

                <textarea rows="30" cols="22" id="txtHtmlHead" class="editor"></textarea>
```

The above textarea behaves as a ckeditor .

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.open()` with a tricky `url` to do that ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/3LUKu/)):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    plugins: 'sourcearea,wysiwygarea,toolbar,basicstyles',
    height: 100
} );

// Executen on button click.
function show() {
    var url = 'javascript:void( function(){' +
        'document.open();' +    
        // Note that you may need to escape HTML entities here:
        'document.write( "' + CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData() + '" );' +
        'document.close();' +
    '})()';    

    window.open( url );
}
```

Such feature is also provided by the official [Preview plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/preview) so you might find it interesting.